# Clean old results while new option chosen in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I get some data by json, and there is small issue.

When I choose some data it returns result to me, but when I choose another data it keeps old result and add new result into it. What I want is to clear old results on new selected data.

[Preview of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpIE9.jpg)

My JavaScript code:

```
<script>
  jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $('body').on('change', 'select[name="city"]', function(e){
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
      });

       var cityID = $(this).val();
        if(cityID) {
            $.ajax({
              url: '{{ url('rajaajax') }}/'+encodeURI(cityID),
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
              success:function(data) {
                $('#des').append(
                  '<p>Destination: ' + data['meta']['destination']['province'] + ' , ' + data['meta']['destination']['type'] + ' , ' + data['meta']['destination']['city_name'] + ' , ' + data['meta']['destination']['postal_code'] +'</p>'
                  );
                $.each(data.data, function(key, value) {
                  console.log();
                  $('#info').append('<h3>'+ value['code'] + '<small>' + value['name'] +'</small></h3>');
                    $.each(value.costs, function(key2, value2) {
                      $.each(value2.cost, function(key3, value3) {
                        $('select[name="postchoose"]').append('<option id="postchoose" class="form-control" value="'+ value3['value'] +'">'+ value2['service'] + ' - ' + value3['value'] + ' - ' + value3['etd'] +'</option>');
                      });
                    });
                });
              }
            });
        }else{
          console.log(data);
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

My HTML Code:

```
<div id="calcul" style="margin-top: 30px;">
  <div id="des"></div>
  <dev id="info"></dev>
  <select name="postchoose" id="">
    <option class="form-control" value="">Select Shiping Method</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user .empty() method before appending the new data,

```
<script>
  jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $('body').on('change', 'select[name="city"]', function(e){
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
      });

       var cityID = $(this).val();
        if(cityID) {
            $.ajax({
              url: '{{ url('rajaajax') }}/'+encodeURI(cityID),
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
              success:function(data) {
              $('#des').empty();
                $('#des').append(
                  '<p>Destination: ' + data['meta']['destination']['province'] + ' , ' + data['meta']['destination']['type'] + ' , ' + data['meta']['destination']['city_name'] + ' , ' + data['meta']['destination']['postal_code'] +'</p>'
                  );
                $.each(data.data, function(key, value) {
                  $('#info').empty();
                  $('select[name="postchoose"]').empty();
                  $('#info').append('<h3>'+ value['code'] + '<small>' + value['name'] +'</small></h3>');
                    $.each(value.costs, function(key2, value2) {
                      $.each(value2.cost, function(key3, value3) {
                        $('select[name="postchoose"]').append('<option id="postchoose" class="form-control" value="'+ value3['value'] +'">'+ value2['service'] + ' - ' + value3['value'] + ' - ' + value3['etd'] +'</option>');
                      });
                    });
                });
              }
            });
        }else{
          console.log(data);
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```